# SQL Now() parse date only

Tags: mysql

For the following query

```
SELECT 
Now() + INTERVAL FLOOR(RAND()*(1000-5+1)+5) DAY as 'Due Date',
device_serial as "Device Serial",
customer_name as "Customer",
error_code as 'Error Code',
resolutiom as 'Resolution'
FROM preventive_maintenance
ORDER BY 'Due Date' desc
LIMIT 25
```

How can I parse 'Due Date' to be displayed in the format 2-Feb-2019

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code. Also 'Due Date' is a string

Comment: can you recommend?

Comment: What do you mean "parse"? What exactly do you want the outcome of your code to be? What is the problem so far? Do you mean you want to render the values in the `Due Date` column according to a particular date format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's best to do this in application code, where it can be rendered according to the locale of your end user, but if you must do it in MySQL then DATE_FORMAT is the function to use, e.g.:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2019-02-02','%a-%b-%y') x;
+------------+
| x          |
+------------+
| Sat-Feb-19 |
+------------+
```

Comment: Thanks, 
I know it best to be randomized in the application, this is grafana sample dashboard I am using without any backend. nevertheless, I want to put Now() + INTERVAL FLOOR(RAND()*(1000-5+1)+5) DAY as 'Due Date', as input

Comment: @user829174 So don't let me stop you

Comment: @user829174 Use DATEFORMAT as suggested e.g. SELECT DATE_FORMAT(Now() + INTERVAL FLOOR(RAND()*(1000-5+1)+5) DAY, ) as 'Due Date';

Answer (score -1):

I've used CURDATE() instead of on Now()

```
SELECT 
DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(curdate(), INTERVAL FLOOR(RAND()*(1000-5+1)+5) DAY), '%d-%b-%y') as 'Due Date',
device_serial as "Device Serial",
customer_name as "Customer",
error_code as 'Error Code',
resolutiom as 'Resolution'
FROM preventive_maintenance
ORDER BY 'Due Date' desc
LIMIT 25
```

Comment: It's meaningless to sort by a constant.